# How to resize a volume in an instance on OpenStack?

Tags: openstack, disk-volume

check using volume from list

```
openstack volume list
```

set status to `available` to a volume

```
openstack volume set --state available [volume id]
```

resize the volume

```
openstack volume set --size 40 [volume id]
```

check size and status again

```
Openstack volume show [volume id]
```

status become `in-use`, size become 40. It's attached to /dev/vda.

However, login into the vm, use `df -h` check, didn't find `/dev/vda`.

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/vda1        20G  1.8G   19G   9% /
devtmpfs        1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           1.9G   17M  1.9G   1% /run
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           379M     0  379M   0% /run/user/1000
```

Why it doesn't change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Openstack just increases the physical disk size.  You will need to use the operating system utilities to increase the disk space allocated to / for example.

Answer (score 5):

I had exactly same issue. Than i found the solution, here's mine :

**After you finally resize the Volume from Ceph (Like the question above)**

#### Login to your VM

```
## Grow part (i.e resize root partition)
sudo growpart /dev/vda 1

## Check if already extend
lsblk

## Resize ‘/’ file system to fill all space on the partition
sudo resize2fs /dev/vda1

## (option) If your filesystem is XFS, it can be grown while mounted using the xfs_growfs command:

sudo xfs_growfs /

## Verify
sudo df -H
```

I wrote about my prod case [here](https://nicolas.my.id/resize-root-volume-openstack-without-downtime/).

Comment: Hi Nicolas - can you clarify how your answer builds on the others and is different from them? Thanks!

Comment: My answer is no different I'm just wrapping up everything from the first answer and another reference. Also, I didn't see any mention `growpart` command which is the key for this resize action.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue, and it was not clear for me how to resize the partition if you use an openstack volume. This did it for me:

Start with unmounting
sudo umount /dev/sdb

Then make the system aware of the new size:

```
sudo e2fsck -f /dev/sdb
```

After that you can resize the volume

```
sudo resize2fs /dev/sdb
```

Finally mount the volume and check if the new filesize is set

```
sudo mount /dev/sdb /mount_point
df -h
```

Comment: Note that you should first use `cfdisk /dev/sdb` and resize the partition before you can resize the filesystem using `e2fsck -f /dev/sdb && resize2fs /dev/sdb`